# Does the limit of this sequence exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

While practicing for an exam, I encountered this question:
(e) For a sequence $\lbrace b_n \rbrace_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}$ is given: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\: b_n < b_{n+1} < 2$.

Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exist? If $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ exists, give $\lim_{n\to\infty}$and explain the answer. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ does not exist, explain the answer.

My thought process: The limit exists $\Longleftrightarrow $ if $\exists n$ such that $b_n=b_{n+1}$. And because this contradicts with the fact that $b_n < b_{n+1}$. Hence, the limit does not exist.

A classmate on mine had an other answer: "Since $b_{n+1}>b_n$ but $b_{n+1} < 2$, we know that $b_{n+1}$ is closer to 2 than $b_n$. He deduces from this that the limit is 2.

Who of us is right?

Comment: Both of you are wrong: the limit exists, but it may not be equal to $2$.

Comment: For your claim, the sequence $b_n = 2-\frac{1}{n}$ satisfies $b_n\neq b_{n+1},\,\forall n$, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n = 2$.

Comment: In a similar manner, for your friend's claim, think about the sequence $1.9876-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: hint: consider $\beta = \sup\{(b_n): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: ... and $b_n=1-\frac1n$ satisfies the condition of the problem as well, its limit exists but is $\ne 2$.

Comment: Do you know about supremums? What is $\sup_{n\to\infty} b_n$? Think *carefully* about this problem. It encapsulates quite a lot of very fundamental ("introductory") knowledge of real analysis.

Comment: You might want to read the article on the Monotone Convergence Theorem on Wikipedia (or elsewhere).

Comment: Your thought would be correct if we endowed $\mathbb R$ with the discrete topology - which we don't, I guess.

Comment: @LordSoth So, the limit does exist but there are infinitely many of them? So it is an ill defined problem?

Comment: @B.Mackey $\beta =2$? Does that imply that $lim_{n\to\infty} b_n < 2$?

Comment: @rogerl If I understand the wikipage correctly: since the sequence is increasing and bounded, it converges to the supremum. Since the supremum is 2, it converges to 2?

Comment: @NigelOvermars we are given $b_n \leq 2$ for every $n$, so by the definition of supremum, $\beta \leq 2.$ The fact that $b_n$ converges to $\beta$ is an extremely important fact which relies only on the definition of a supremum the definition of limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence is increasing and bounded. Thus it is convergent.

The limit $l$ satisfies $l \leq 2$, but as it was pointed it is not necessarily $2$. For each $ l\leq 2$
$$b_n =l -\frac{1}{n}$$

is an example of a sequence satisfying the conditions and converging to $l$.